Hinduism in Latin America
Has there been any evidence of Vedic practices in Central America? As it is historically a breeding ground for a medley of religion and spirituality.

You may read about Paracas Candelabra which has a Trishula-like symbol and King Viracocha who is said to be the same as Virochana. But it can't be fully verified.
